# How to get the Xpath of the value which is under p tag inside the header

Tags: html, xml, web, web-scraping, xpath

How can I extract ingredient list inside the `<p>` tag? I tried few things and was able to get till header - Ingredients. I am look to extract the value which should be aligned with header - Ingredients.

Path I tried:

`//DIV[@id="important-information"]//h4[text()='Ingredients:']/text()`

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this xpath to locate the 2nd p tag element highlighted in the image. Below xpath can be used in automation as it will return the web element-

```
//div[@id="important-information”]//div[2]//p[2]
```

And if you directly want to get the text from xpath then use below xpath-

```
//div[@id="important-information”]//div[2]//p[2]/text()
```

Comment: I am looking for dynamic solution where the value corresponds to header - Ingredients

Comment: In that case you can use this xpath-
//h4[text()='Ingredients:']/following-sibling::p[2]/text()

Comment: HI SelectorsHub , the previous answer was working fine which you have edited. Can you please change back

Comment: I haven't edited any answer. The above xpath is same.